# React.js: How to define a default property function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component uses a function to render some inner text. I'd like to allow the owner of my component to provide a custom function as a property. If no custom property is provided, the component will use it's own default function. So naturally, I turned to `getDefaultProps` like so:

```
propTypes: function() {       
  renderText: React.PropTypes.func
};

getDefaultProps: function() {
  return {
    renderText: this._renderText
  };
}
```

The problem is that `_renderText` is `undefined` when `getDefaultProps` is called.
I can get around this by checking if `this.props.renderText` is defined and falling back to `this._renderText` if needed. But his doesn't feel like the React way of doing things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would work if you defined `renderText` function:

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
  return {
    renderText: function() {
      // do sth
    }
  };
}
```

I don't think you can use `this` like you've tried, because:

> getDefaultProps
>
> This method is invoked before any instances are created and thus cannot rely on `this.prop`

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getdefaultprops

Comment: Thanks! 
I've written a little proof of concept fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8grf4bso/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Class Test extends Component{
    contrustor(props){
    ...
    }
    notify(data){
        console.log("Yeah!",data);
    }
    return (<div>This is context here.</div>)
}
Test.defaultProps={
    getNotify:Test.prototype.notify
}
```

this solution works fine in react-router even no Redux or Flux and so on.