# Alternative props in DefaultProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to use the alternative props in the default props declaration?

example code:

```
Sample.defaultProps = {
  color: 'red',
  background: this.props.color
}
```

Comment: What even is the point of doing this?

Comment: this is just a sample code, I am looking for a way that one props would alternatively take the value of the second props

Comment: `defaultProps` would be a static property, so you cannot access `this.props` inside it.

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369598/react-js-how-to-define-a-default-property-function might help